# sinon fake server.requests returns an empty array

Tags: mocha.js, sinon

I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, I just followed their documentation.

I'm using mocha + sinonjs

actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const attachmentActions = {
   getAttachment(id) {
      axios.get('/api/attachment/${id}')
           .then(response => {
              console.log(respons);
           })
           .catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
           }) 
   }
}
export const actions = {
   ...attachmentActions,
}
```

actions.test.js

```
describe('actions-test', () => {
   let server;
   beforeEach(() => {
      server = sinon.createFakeServer();
   });
   afterEach(() => {
      server.restore();
   })

   it('call getAttachment', () => {
      server.requests[0].respond(200, 
      {'Content-type':'application/json'}, 
       JSON.stringify({mimeType: 'image/png', path: '/user/image/'}));
      actions.getAttachment(1)
      //assertion
   })
})
```

With the code above I got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'respond' of undefined`

I also tried below

```
it('call getAttachment', () => {
   server.respondWith('GET','/api/attachment/1',[200, 
   {'Content-type':'application/json'}, 
   JSON.stringify({mimeType: 'image/png', path: '/user/image/'}))];

   actions.getAttachment(1);
   server.respond();
      //assertion
})
```

but when I run the test axios returns 404

Would really appreciate if someone can pinpoint if I miss something?

`sinon version: 7.3.2`